# Nodejs won't install : An error occurred while applying security settings. Authenticathed Users is not a valid user or group

Tags: node.js, installation

I have a problem since yesterday, I made the error of uninstalling Nodejs to put the latest version (14.17.2 LTS OR 16.4.1 Current) and since I have this error ... I do not understand, this is my personal pc and I am the admin (normally) I do not understand either how to solve this problem and in the meantime I can no longer work ...

I've been looking for solutions since yesterday but can't find what I need to do to fix it ..

(PS: excuse my English, I'm French)

I attach you the capture of my administrator account
Windows 10

[Error Nodejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7QhU.png)

[administrator account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gq6W.pngz)

MAJ 06/july/2021:

I finally managed to cheat the thing, downloaded the Nodejs ZIP folder, and put it straight to my hard drive and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) as administrator and type or copy/paste:

```
net localgroup /add "Authenticated Users"
```

Then click the "Retry" button or run the installation file again.

Comment: thanks for your help, i finally found another solution if you look at my first post.